# c# - Под конец отдельного потока программа закрывается

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Идет у меня таков поток.

```
Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
                            {
                                //Много-много кода в потоке который грузит файлы из интернета

                                u("Завершение установки..."); //Просто записывает текст в файл

                                Form d = new Form5();
                                d.Show();
                                this.Close();
                            });
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
```

Под конец его работы открывается другая форма а нынешняя закрывается.
Но результат совершенно другой, другая форма на мгновение открывается после чего и первая и вторая форма закрываются а процесс программы продолжает висеть на фоне. Я предположил что проблема в потоке так-как вызов формы у меня один и тот-же и везде он работает, вот только тут что-то не так.

На всякий случай, Program.cs

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Form d = new Form1();
d.Show();
Application.Run();
```

Собственно вопрос - что я упустил? Почему по окончании работы потока все формы закрываются а процесс программы остается висеть на фоне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в этой строке:

```
this.Close();
```

this - это главная форма приложения, то поведение программы нормально. Нельзя закрывать главную форму. Но ее можно скрывать. Например, вызывая метод Hide. Плюс, у вас там Exception возникает. Т.к. нельзя работать с визуальным элементом из потока отличного от того, в котором он создан. Как то так должен код выглядеть:

```
Thread t = new Thread(delegate ()
{
    //Много-много кода в потоке который грузит файлы из интернета


    this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            Form d = new Form5();
            d.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }));
});
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

Но тут вам надо будет думать, как главную форму закрыть, чтобы все приложение остановить.